# How to restrict the page from redirect after login/ logout in Angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

I need to restrict the user from redirect and need to login only with authentication.

I tried but I can redirect to login page using back button and again come to same page using forward button. Even I can go to the required page using URL without login.

**My code :**

```
config.$inject = ['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider'];
    function config($routeProvider, $locationProvider ) {

        $routeProvider

            .when('/login', {
                controller: 'LoginController',
                templateUrl: 'view/login.view.html',
                controllerAs: 'vm'
            })

            .when('/profileData', {
                controller: 'profileDataController',
                templateUrl: 'view/profiledata.view.html',
                controllerAs :'vm'
            })

            .when('/questionBank', {
                controller: 'questionbankController',
                templateUrl: 'view/questionbank.view.html',
                controllerAs: 'vm'
            })

            .when('/dashboard', {
              //  controller: 'PersonalInfoController',
                templateUrl: 'view/dashboard.view.html',
                controllerAs:'vm'
            })

            .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/login' });

    }

    run.$inject = ['$rootScope', '$location', '$cookieStore', '$http'];
    function run($rootScope, $location, $cookieStore, $http) {
        // keep user logged in after page refresh
        $rootScope.globals  = $cookieStore.get('globals') || {};


        if ($rootScope.globals.currentUser) {
            $http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Basic ' + $rootScope.globals.currentUser.authdata; // jshint ignore:line
        }

         $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function (event, next, current) {
            //redirect to login page if not logged in and trying to access a restricted page

             var restrictedPage = $.inArray($location.path(), ['/dashboard','/questionBank', '/profileData']) === -1;

/*            var a    = $location.$$absUrl.split('#')[1];
              var patt = new RegExp(a);
              var res  = patt.test(restrictedPage); */

              var loggedIn = $rootScope.globals.currentUser;

            if (restrictedPage && !loggedIn) {
                $location.path('/login');

            }  
        }); 
}
```

Comment: Just Perfom Some Authentication From Server And Client Side.
And On Each Request To Server Check The Existence Of The User If Session Is Timed Out Just Redirect Him To Login Page Using State

Answer (score 1):

use this :based on response from server

```
.when('/login', {
                     controller: 'LoginController',
                     templateUrl: 'view/login.view.html',
                    resolve:{
            logincheck: checklogedin
        })


    / resolve function for user....
    var checklogedin = function($q ,$http,$location)
    {   

        var deferred =$q.defer();

        $http.get('/loggedin').success(function(user){

            if (user.staus==true)
            {
                //goo
                deferred.resolve();
            }
           else 
           {
               deferred.reject();
               $location.url('/login');
           }

        });
        return deferred.promise
    };
```

Comment: This showing error to me "angular.min.js:6 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.3/$injector/modulerr?p0=app&p1=ReferenceErr…20at%20Hd%20(http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A51281%2Fjs%2Fangular.min.js%3A17%3A1)"

Comment: i think u done some other mistake....use simple code and try ( var checklogedin = function($q ,$http,$location)
{   
  alert("hi")
    var permission = true;
 var deferred =$q.defer();
 if(permission == false)
   {
    $location.url('/home');
    deferred.reject();
   }else
   {
    $location.url('/about');
    deferred.resolve();
   }
 return deferred.promise
}; )

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code that you have provided, I can't tell 100% what is going on in your code. But... you could always try to use the `resolve` property on each route that you don't want to allow access without authentication. Here is what that would look like for `questionBank`:

```
.when('/questionBank', {
    controller: 'questionbankController',
    templateUrl: 'view/questionbank.view.html',
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    resolve: {
        auth: function(AuthService, $q){
            if(AuthService.isAuthenticated()) return $q.resolve();
            return $q.reject();
        }
    }
})
```

Each property of the resolve object should return a promise, and if that resolves... the route change works. If it rejects... the route change is not allowed. If the promise never resolves, you are screwed, so make sure it resolves or it will never do the route.

This isn't the only way to try what you are saying. It is A way of trying it.

Answer (score 0):

You can also add event listener on your $scope and prevent moving in case of unauthenticated user.

```
$scope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function (event, next, current) {
    if (!is_logged_in) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In my code I have two main controllers `LoginCtrl` and `AppCtrl`, and all other controllers are nested within `AppCtrl`. Then in `AppCtrl` I have this code, which will check for logged user.

`if (localStorageService.get('authToken') === null) {
    $state.go('login', {locale: CONFIG.defaultLang});
} else if (!userService.isLoggedIn()) {
    tokenStorage.setAuthToken(localStorageService.get('authToken'));
    userService.setIdentity(JSON.parse(localStorageService.get('user')));
}`

As you can see I store auth token from server in local storage. When page loades this code will be executed and if you are not logged in you will be redirected. And because all other application controllers are nested within `AppCtrl` this code will be executed every time.

For more info about nested controllers try for example this article - https://rclayton.silvrback.com/parent-child-controller-communication